# How to make an activity node flicker color in GOJS

Tags: gojs

I want to randomly change the color of activity node in GOJS. i have this requirement where a user will visit a page where there are two GOJS diagrams and in both the diagrams there is some similarity in the node. I want to randomly highlight the activity Node for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "highlight" one or more nodes (or really, any Part), there are mainly two ways to do so that are built into GoJS.

First, there is the **Diagram.selection** collection and **Part.isSelected** property and methods on Diagram for selecting parts.  This is described at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/selection.html.

Second, there is the **Diagram.highlighteds** collection and **Part.isHighlighted** property and methods on Diagram for choosing highlighted parts.  This is described at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/highlighting.html.

Choose selection if you expect the user to do something with the selected part(s), such as look at and maybe edit their properties in a separate HTML panel, or move/copy/delete them, or perform some desired operation on them.  Many predefined commands and tools change or operate on the selection.

Choose highlighting if you just want to draw attention to them by making them visually distinct.  No command or tool changes or uses the highlighteds collection.

Both selection and highlighting offer customized visual changes, normally based on data binding.  Selection also offers showing Adornments, separate Parts that are associated with a selected Part, which is predefined behavior that works with every Part.  But that can be customized too, as the [Introduction page on Selection](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/selection.html) demonstrates.

So you just need to find the Node in each Diagram that you want to "highlight", and then set either **Part.isSelected** or **Part.isHighlighted**.  No template changes are required if you are using selection; or you can customize the visual changes by adding data bindings on "isSelected" or on "isHighlighted" `.ofObject()`.  For examples, see the section about [Highlighting Nodes and Links](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/highlighting.html).

Lots of samples use selection; you might find the Org Chart (static) sample useful to demonstrate a typical use of highlighting: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartStatic.html.  Enter some text to search for in the text box.

Or look at the Distances and Paths sample: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/distances.html.

Oh, if you really want to randomly change the color of some Shape or TextBlock or some GraphObject.background, you might find the **Brush.randomColor** static method useful: http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Brush.html#.randomColor